# Can I overwrite a library capsule's NoResult dialog?

Tags: bixby

Is it possible for a capsule developer to overwrite a library capsule's NoResult dialog by using the same match patterns that are in the library capsule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If your capsule’s resource has a match pattern that is equally specific or more specific, it will have priority over the library’s resource.